# How do I use ag to look for text in files with certain extensions?

Tags: files, search, ag

I'm using `ag` ([The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)) version 0.31.0.  I can easily look for a string in a bunch of files using:

```
localhost:workspace davea$ ag 'ftp' .
```

But what if I only want to scan files with certain extensions?  I tried this:

```
localhost:workspace davea$ ag 'ftp' .java
ERR: Error stat()ing: .java
ERR: Error opening directory .java: No such file or directory
```

but got the errors you see above.

Comment: Gave that a whirl but got "ERR: Error stat()ing: *.java" and "ERR: Error opening directory *.java: No such file or directory" errors

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Per the manual, you could use `ag` with `-G`

```
   -G --file-search-regex PATTERN
          Only search files whose names match PATTERN.
```

e.g.

```
ag -G '\.java$' 'ftp' .
```

Per the same manual

```
   It is possible to restrict the types of files searched [...]
   For a list of supported types, run ag --list-file-types.
```

So you could also run

```
ag --java 'ftp' .
```

though that would restrict the search to file names ending in `.java` or `.properties`

Comment: oops sorry, deleting.

Comment: ` ag -G '\.(hbs|html)$' keyword ` if you are searching multiple file extensions

Comment: works perfectly with Cygwin on Windows 10 64bit. For example to search for word avg across all .xml files, I used this:  ag -G '.xml' avg

Answer (score 6):

As of `ag version 2.2.0`, you can run `ag --list-file-types`, which will list supported, out-of-the-box types. You can run `ag "ftp" --java` and search against only varying Java files.